# Using implicit def with composed types

Tags: scala, types, implicit-conversion

Forgive me if this question is a duplicate; I'm having trouble finding anything because I don't know the right words to search. So, with implicit def, I can do things like this:

```
type CharsetMap = Map[Charset, Byte]

implicit def seqtup2CharsetMap(input: Seq[(String, Int)]): CharsetMap = {
  Map.empty  // placeholder
}

def somef(a: Int, b:Int, p: CharsetMap) = p
somef(1, 3, Seq(("hey", 2), ("there", 9)))
```

which lets me call `somef` with a Seq[(String, Int)] object as a parameter. The problem is that I have something like this...

```
def somef2(p: (CharsetMap) => Int) = p
```

and this does not work:

```
val p = (a: Seq[(String, Int)]) => 19
somef2(p)
```

How can I do this without doing an `implicit def` specifically for `(Seq[(String, Int)]) => Int`?

Comment: Any reason that your `p` function cannot take a `Charset` parameter, while you plug in `Seq[(String, Int)]` value when invoking it?

Comment: @Kane, maybe not, but I think so. So the context is that I'm using Playframework's Scalaforms DSL and I'm trying to convert an HTML form input into a `CharsetMap` by using `seq` and `tuple`. I think maybe I could write something similar to `seq` that returns a Map instead of a Seq, but I was hoping that I could just do it with implicit def.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to implicitly convert some function `A => B` to a function that goes from `C => B`. You can do that with this generic implicit:

```
implicit def f2InputConverter[A, B, C](f: A => B)(implicit i: C => A): C => B = (c: C) => f(i(c))
```

Once you have that in scope, in your particular case, you'll need an implicit function which is the inverse of the one that you've defined in the question:

```
implicit def charsetMap2Seqtup(input: CharsetMap): Seq[(String, Int)] = {
  Nil  // placeholder
}
```

and then you should be able to call `somef2` with `p`

Comment: For some reason, my ABCs went the other way. Just to show alt syntax, `implicit def fg[A,B,C](f: Function1[B,C])(implicit cv: Function1[A,B]): Function1[A,C] = cv andThen f`

Comment: That is quite nicer. I'm probably wrong, but I think this pattern is just a Functor. Basically given an A => B the functor lifts it into F[A] => F[B]. F, in this case, would be Function2[_, T] . What I can't get my head around is why, for that F, we need a B => A to get an F[A] => F[B].

Comment: Wow, that's pretty insane. So I simplified it in my question, but for my actual use case `somef2` actually takes a function with 8 parameters. I was hoping to find a flexible solution that wouldn't require changing as parameters grew/shrank, maybe I'll just take a different approach than `implicit def`s.

Comment: Here's the necessary def when the function in question takes 8 parameters: `implicit def f2InputConverter[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J](fun: (A,D,E, F, G, H, I, J) => B)(implicit imp: C => A): (C,D,E, F, G, H, I, J) => B = (c: C, d:D, e:E, f:F, g:G, h:H, i:I, j:J) => fun(imp(c),d,e,f,g,h,i,j)`
this has the major caveat that it only works when the parameter you're converting is the 1st parameter.